# useContext Error while using Components of Material UI in react project

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, runtime-error

I am trying to simply use Button component of Material UI in my react code. Earlier in other projects, Material UI componenets used to work fine after including the pacakege in the project. But now whcih ever component i try to use, i am facing this error every single time about some code in the Material UI component. There is something i am not doing right.

I installed the material ui pacakege using this npm commaand:
`npm install @mui/material @emotion/react @emotion/styled`

index.js:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import { StyledEngineProvider } from '@mui/material/styles';
import App from './App'

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector("#root")).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <StyledEngineProvider injectFirst>
      <App />
    </StyledEngineProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

App.js:

```
import {  Button } from "@mui/material";
export default function App() {
    return (

     <div>
        <h1>Final Project</h1>
        <Button variant="contained">Hello World</Button>
        </div>
        
    );
}
```

the Error i am getting in the counsole:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext')
    at Object.useContext (react.development.js:1618:1)
    at Button (Button.js:223:1)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16305:1)
    at updateForwardRef (react-dom.development.js:19226:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21636:1)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27426:1)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:26557:1)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:26466:1)
    at renderRootSync (react-dom.development.js:26434:1)
    at recoverFromConcurrentError (react-dom.development.js:25850:1)
```

Comment: Same code works fine on sandBox.

Comment: did you use a template to create the project or npx? This looks very much like incompatible versions between the packages.

Comment: I used npx.  It's good that you have mentioned it. I am going to reinstall node js to have the latest versions of packages.

Comment: @M.Jafar - did this help? What installation commands did you use for react and Material UI?

Comment: It appears that create-react-app is no longer maintained. Are you creating react projects differently?