# Material UI useContext dependen

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-context

I have an issue very similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76760446/usecontext-error-while-using-components-of-material-ui-in-react-project) question. (See below)
My question is, what versions of React and Material UI should be installed and how?

```
import * as React from 'react';
import {Button} from '@mui/material';

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Button>hello</Button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Material UI Button uses useContext hook but is not using it appropriately.

```
ERROR
Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext')
    at Object.useContext (http://localhost:3000/main.1060eb1d58db4786d492.hot-update.js:12575:25)
    at Button (http://localhost:3000/main.1060eb1d58db4786d492.hot-update.js:2470:59)
    at renderWithHooks (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:21336:22)
    at updateForwardRef (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:23907:24)
    at beginWork (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:25954:20)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:10928:18)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:10972:20)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:11029:35)
    at beginWork$1 (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:30903:11)
    at performUnitOfWork (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:30150:16)
```

Note: I installed/used `create-react-app` as my method of getting react. However, I've read that this is no longer maintained.

Edit: Package.json listed

```
   {
  "name": "my-material-ui-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.14.8",
    "@mui/material": "^5.14.8",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.17.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
    
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you add `package.json` contents to your question?

Comment: I think packages `@emotion/react` and `@emotion/styled` are missing, did you try installing them?